# Docker commit image starts node repl instead of serving a website

Tags: node.js, docker, containers

Goal is to NOT use a Dockerfile but to create a container, modify a container, then commit an image based off the container. It is for a course I am giving feedback on and I can NOT use a Dockerfile.

I have a folder, node-test-application with the following on an Ubuntu machine:
package.json  server.js

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "docker_web_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js on Docker",
  "author": "First Last <first.last@example.com>",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.1"
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
    
// Constants
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';
    
// App
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World');
});
    
app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

So this is the order of operations I'm following from within node-test-application:
Run intermediate node container

```
docker run -d -t --name nodeint -p 3009:8080 node:16
```

copy files from

```
docker container cp . nodeint:/app
```

then I enter the container:

```
docker exec -it nodeint sh
```

Now inside the container, I cd into app directory:

```
cd app
```

My files are present:
package.json  server.js

I run npm install:

```
npm install
```

```
added 57 packages, and audited 58 packages in 3s

7 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.11.0 -> 8.12.1
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.12.1
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.12.1 to update!
npm notice
```

I run npm start:

```
npm start
```

```
> docker_web_app@1.0.0 start
> node server.js

Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

I go to IPADDRESS:3009
And it's serving "Hello World" to the browser.

So now I ctrl+c then ctrl+d and I'm out of the container.

`docker ps` shows that the container is still running.

So I:

```
docker commit nodeint nodeapp:v1
```

and it returns the image ID

Now I expect to be able to run a container with the nodeapp:v1 image and have it serve me Hello World on the IPADDRESS:3010 port after I run the following command:

```
docker run -it --name nodeappcont -p 3010:8080 nodeapp:v1
```

but it gives me a node REPL:

```
Welcome to Node.js v16.15.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
>
```

And when I navigate to IPADDRESS:3010 I get nothing. Just site can't be reached.

When I run image history:

```
docker image history nodeapp:v1
IMAGE          CREATED         CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
ebf532979d69   3 minutes ago   node                                            5.83MB    
b59df4e04d61   2 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["node"]                 0B        
<missing>      2 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entry…   0B        
<missing>      2 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:4d192565a7220e13…   388B      
<missing>      2 days ago      /bin/sh -c set -ex   && for key in     6A010…   7.6MB     
<missing>      2 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV YARN_VERSION=1.22.19     0B        
<missing>      2 days ago      /bin/sh -c ARCH= && dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print…   95.3MB    
<missing>      2 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV NODE_VERSION=16.15.1     0B        
<missing>      12 days ago     /bin/sh -c groupadd --gid 1000 node   && use…   334kB     
<missing>      12 days ago     /bin/sh -c set -ex;  apt-get update;  apt-ge…   510MB     
<missing>      12 days ago     /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   146MB     
<missing>      12 days ago     /bin/sh -c set -ex;  if ! command -v gpg > /…   17.5MB    
<missing>      12 days ago     /bin/sh -c set -eux;  apt-get update;  apt-g…   16.5MB    
<missing>      12 days ago     /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B        
<missing>      12 days ago     /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:5c5cde050dbdbd5c7…   114MB
```

So how do I create an node image from a container with changes that will serve a node app? Remember, without using a Dockerfile.

Comment: send your dockerfile

Comment: @Moeinmoeinnia, looks like you didn't read the question.  It says _I can NOT use a Dockerfile._

Comment: The `docker commit` workflow you describe is not really a best practice at all.  Imagine coming back to this project a year later being told there's a critical security vulnerability and you _must_ update the underlying Node engine; how will you do it with an image where you have no record of how you created it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker commit` only saves the file system of the container. It doesn't save any running processes.

You can change the working directory and the start command, by using the `--change`/`-c` option on `docker commit` to apply Dockerfile statements from the command line. In your case, you could do

```
docker commit -c 'WORKDIR /app' -c 'CMD npm start' nodeint nodeapp:v1
```

Then you can run it with

```
docker run -it --name nodeappcont -p 3010:8080 nodeapp:v1
```

and `npm start` will run in the `/app` directory.

Comment: So really the only way to do what I am trying to do is with a Dockerfile. Because with a Dockerfile you CAN create an image that will run an immediately serving application correct?

Comment: Wait a minute though, in this tutorial they seem to be able to do it with nginx. https://thenewstack.io/tutorial-create-a-docker-image-from-a-running-container/

Comment: Nginx works because they don't need to change the start command of the image. I looked at the docs and you can add Dockerfile commands to the `docker commit` command. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it's certainly the best way but can you elaborate on "start command" not needing to be changed for nginx but needing to be changed for node? Can one change the "start command" on a node image or does it already have to be baked in?

Comment: The Dockerfile for the node image you run is here: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/194a775693fd40598a1bafd4858e063c24efeb42/16/buster/Dockerfile. As you can see at the bottom, it defines an entrypoint script with the default input (the CMD) `node`. That's why you get the interactive node shell when you just run your image. You need to change that, so it'll run `npm start` instead, since that's the process you want to run. If you change the CMD to 'npm start' then the container will run that on startup, rather than the 'node' command.

Comment: I gotcha. Literally nginx will run the server whereas node runs a REPL and the nginx image runs nginx while the node runs node.